# Embedding JSSOR slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, jssor

I am trying to embed the slider into my site, but I am getting the white squares stacked 3 high (3 different slides) when I test it.  I am new with javascript and clearly missed something.  I wanted there to be a slider with 3 slides that could be clicked to take the user to another page.  Where did I go wrong?

Javascript:

```
 <script src="jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        var options = {
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    };
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
    height: 300px; ">

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div><a u="image" href="sermon.html"><img src="pic05.jpg" /></a></div>
        <div><a u="image" href="sunday.html"><img src="pic06.jpg" /></a></div>
        <div><a u="image" href="mdeia.html"><img src="media.jpg" /></a></div>

    </div>

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 03 css */
        /*
        .jssora03l              (normal)
        .jssora03r              (normal)
        .jssora03l:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora03r:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora03ldn            (mousedown)
        .jssora03rdn            (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora03l, .jssora03r, .jssora03ldn, .jssora03rdn
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(../img/a03.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .jssora03l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora03r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora03l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
        .jssora03r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
        .jssora03ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
        .jssora03rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">jQuery Slider</a>
    <!-- Trigger -->
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    </script>
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

Comment: Is the 'jssor.slider.min.js' in the same folder of your page?

Comment: I have just tested and it worked. Please make sure the reference path of 'jssor.slider.min.js' is correct.

Comment: I had it in my javascript folder with the other scripts on the page.  I moved it to my root folder housing the html files and still couldn't get the slideshow to display.  I still get the red X's stack on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Which folder is your page in? And which folder is the 'jssor.slider.mini.js' in?

Comment: Originally the page was in a separate folder and the jssor.slider.mini.js wasn't on my site.  I moved the jssor.slider.min.js and now I can see the first image, but it is left justified and there are no navigation arrows.  Do I need the jssor.slider.mini.js and the jssor.slider.min.js?

Comment: Any url that I can have a look?

Comment: I will launch it and then come back and post a link.

Comment: Please check out www.lofmemphis.com.  Thank you so much for your assistance so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your page, and I found you placed the 'jssor.slider.mini.js' in root folder.

So, the correct reference path is,

```
<script src="/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
```

Btw, the 'jssor.slider.min.js' and 'jssor.slider.mini.js' are the same, you need only one.

Please remove the following line,

```
<script src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

And you have no initialization code, please add the following code,

```
<script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    };
</script>
```

And also, please move a03.png to your `[root]/img` folder.

Comment: I removed the <script src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script> line and corrected the path, but it is still hanging out on the left side of the screen without arrows.  Is there something I need to add to the css in the page?

Comment: Yes!  That fixed it.  Thank you again for all of your help along the way.  You have been truly amazing.